# html width stucked to 1400px - from ipynb file using quarto render

Tags: html, css, jupyter-lab, quarto

I have an ipynb file that I want to export as html (working with the R kernel in jupyterlab). I use quarto to do that :

```
quarto render myfile.ipynb
```

The ipynb file I have here is a test file named hello.ipynb that is available here : [Quarto tutorial](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/jupyter.html)

Here is what I have at the top of this file :

```
---
title: "Quarto Basics"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
    toc: true
    css: styles.css
jupyter: R
---
```

Here is what I have in styles.css (I raised max-width to 2000px):

```
body            
{
   margin:5em;
   max-width:2000px;
   width:2000px;
   padding:10px; 
   background-color:#ebebeb;
   font-size:22px; 
   font-family:Verdana;
}
```

Here is what I got :

[image: Screenshot]

**My problem is that the width is stucked at 1400px : I get the same result with "width:1400px" and with "width:2000px".**

Here is what I see when inspecting with the dev tools :

[image: Dev tools inspection]

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: `max-width:2000px;` AND `width:2000px;` makes no sense: `width: ...` with a pixel value FIXES the width. `max-width` won't have any effect in this case.

Comment: Ok I removed max-width. My problem is that the width I got is not 2000px, but 1400px : I have the same result with "width:1400px" and with "width:2000px".

Comment: @armandfavrot Have you tried using the dev tools in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/) or [Firefox](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/#:~:text=You%20can%20open%20the%20Firefox,%2B%20Opt%20%2B%20I%20on%20macOS.)? They're an excellent way to find out what's going on with your page.

Comment: Well given that the whole page's background is grey it seems to be filling your screen as you set. If you want to expand your content you need to change the size of the elements inside the body

Comment: No, the background of the page is always grey, whatever the width. width controls the width of the content between 0 and 1400px (when I set width:1000px, I do get a width of 1000px for the content). It's just that when I go beyond 1400px, nothing changes.

Comment: It could help if you shared a bit more of your CSS though, as we're only seeing the body style. What do you see when inspecting with the dev tools?

Comment: In my styles.css file, I only have the body style. I edited my post with a screenshot of the dev tools inspection. I'm not familiar with all this, so I don't know where to look.

Comment: I can see you have a total of 7 stylesheets (2 embedded and 5 external): styles.css is just one of them. One of them could be overruling styles.css, but it's difficult to tell you which one...